# Proof by induction: $ 2^n \ge n^2$ for $n\ge4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

The first part is clear but in the second I did this:

$2^{n+1}=2^n\cdot 2 \ge n^2\cdot 2=n^2+n^2=n^2+n\cdot n\ge 
n^2+n\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(n+1)^2$

I'm not sure if I the assumption: $n\ge 2+(1/n)$ is correct or I should prove it. Can you help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Ehm, is $2^3\ge3^2$? However the assertion is true for $n>3$; in this case $n>2+\frac{1}{n}$, because $1/n<1$.

Comment: It was for n>=4. Corrected ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to note that, for $n>3$,
$$
\frac{1}{n}<1
$$
so
$$
n>3>2+\frac{1}{n}
$$
Yes, this should be noted in the proof.