# Prove that n squared is less than or equal to 2 to the n by induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, inequality, proof-writing, induction

I've been asked to prove by induction that $n^2\leq 2^n$, and told it is true $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N},n>3$

I think I have found the right way to the proof, but I'm not sure since I get stuck half-way there. What I did was taking a base case of $n=4$ and tested it, and it resulted to be true. Then I assumed it would be true for some number $k$, such that $n=k$ and $k^2\leq 2^k$, and attempted to prove

$(k+1)^2 \leq 2^{k+1}$

And this is how I attempted to prove this. First of all, I started with my assumption.

$=k^2\leq 2^k$

$=2k^2\leq2^{k+1}$

Then I tried to prove that $(k+1)^2 \leq 2k^2$, for this would imply my thesis, i.e. $(k+1)^2\leq2^{k+1}$. So I went forth on my effort:

$(k+1)^2≤2k^2$

$=k^2+2k+1\leq2k^2$

$=2k+1\leq k^2$

(***By assumption***)

$=2k+1\leq 2^k$

Now that I simplified it, I need to prove this is true; this is, prove that $(k+1)^2 \leq 2k^2$. So I take a base case of $n=4$ and in deed it satisfies the inequality. So I assume it is true for some number $j, k=j$ and try to prove it. Nevertheless I have failed in trying to prove this, I don't really know if my steps so far are right or wrong. Is my reasoning okay? And if its, how can I prove $2k+1\leq 2^k$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times already.  Please make an attempt to search for the problem.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319913/proof-that-n2-2n/319938#319938, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263825/proof-of-n2-leq-2n?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263825/proof-of-n2-leq-2n?noredirect=1&lq=1https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496892/induction-proof-n2-2n-for-n-4?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876127/prove-by-induction-that-2n-n2?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489889/proof-by-induction-2n-ge-n2-for-n-ge4?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: When you realize that you must prove $2k + 1<k^2$ !!!! ***DONT*** !!! go back to your assumption to prove $2k+1 < 2^k$.  For one thing proving  $2k + 1< 2^k$ won't prove $k^2 < 2k + 1 < 2^k$ is impossible, but more importantly, you *got* here via the assumption.  Going back will be circular.  You have gotten to the "practical world" where proving $2k+1< k^2$ is your *direct* way of proving your proposition.  So prove it directly.  Prove $2k + 1 < k^2$.  That *should* be easy.

Comment: ... for one thing $k^2 -2k - 1= k^2 - 2k + 1 - 2=(k-1)^2 - 2\ge 3^2 -2 = 7 > 0$ so $k^2 > 2k + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove $2k + 1 \le k^2$.

Do it this way:  $1 < k$ so $2k + 1 < 2k + k = 3k$.  And $3 < k$ so $3k < k^2$.

So to put it together:

Induction step:

If $k^2 < 2^k; k > 3$ then

$(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 < $

$k^2 + 2k + k = k^2 + 3k < $

$k^2 + k*k = 2k^2 < $

$2*2^k = 2^{k+1}$.

.....

.... or simply note...

$2k + 1 < k^2 \iff$

$1 < k^2 - 2k \iff$

$2 < k^2 - 2k + 1 = (k-1)^2$.

And $k-1 \ge 3$ the $(k-1)^2 \ge 9 > 2$.

Comment: Such a neat reasoning, I feel silly I couldn't do this myself, haha. Excelent, @fleablood, I appreciate the fact that you took the trouble to answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: The last line in the first part should probably read $2*2^k \color{red}= 2^{k+1}.$

Comment: ooppps.........